# Is there a way to get the uid of the other end of a unix socket connection

Tags: linux, sockets, dbus, uid, unix-socket

Is there a way for a UNIX domain socket listener to only accept connection from certain user (`chmod`/`chown` does not work for abstract socket afaik), or in another word, get the uid of the incoming connection (on Linux)?

Dbus, which uses abstract unix socket on Linux, has a function `GetConnectionUnixUser` which is used by polkit to determine the caller. So I suppose the `dbus-daemon` must have a way to do that. Does anyone know how that works?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to check peer credentials is with [`SO_PEERCRED`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html).
To do this for socket `sock`:

```
int len;
struct ucred ucred;

len = sizeof(struct ucred);
if (getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PEERCRED, &ucred, &len) == -1)
    // check errno

printf("Credentials from SO_PEERCRED: pid=%ld, euid=%ld, egid=%ld\n",
        (long) ucred.pid, (long) ucred.uid, (long) ucred.gid);
```

> ```
> SO_PEERCRED
>           Return the credentials of the foreign process connected to
>           this socket.  This is possible only for connected AF_UNIX
>           stream sockets and AF_UNIX stream and datagram socket pairs
>           created using socketpair(2); see unix(7).  The returned
>           credentials are those that were in effect at the time of the
>           call to connect(2) or socketpair(2).  The argument is a ucred
>           structure; define the _GNU_SOURCE feature test macro to obtain
>           the definition of that structure from <sys/socket.h>.  This
>           socket option is read-only.
> ```

From a [tlpi](http://man7.org/tlpi/) [example](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/sockets/scm_cred_recv.c.html).  [PostgreSQL](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/getpeereid_8c_source.html) has a few variants for other unices.

Comment: Actually this seems to be what I end up using although I didn't notice the difference between them until now. :P

Comment: It also might be worth mentioning that some Linux systems require you to `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before you `<include ...>` any of the header files in order to get `struct ucred` defined.

Answer (score 4):

Yes -- this operation, along with FD passing, is supported via an ancilliary message with the `SCM_CREDENTIALS` type. The calls involved are documented in [`man 7 unix`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/unix.7.html).

Comment: So by using `SCM_CREDENTIALS` the message is checked by the kernel, but it still require the client to send the message. Is there a way to do this on server side only?

Comment: No; as far as I know, there's no way to get credentials without the other end sending them.

Comment: I C. Probably can check /proc/pid/fd (like what `lsof` does) if really need that ~~