# How to programmatically get PID of process connecting to my proxy via AF_INET sockets, on the same machine?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, pid

I am writing a small http **proxy** server(in C) on a linux machine, Ubuntu 18.04.1 to be specific, and I've been trying to find a way to get the **pid of the process that is connecting to it.**

It might be of use to mention that the proxy is intended to proxy connections only for processes running on the same machine, so I guess this should make this task possible.

The server uses **AF_INET** family sockets along with read/write operations in order to do it's job; I am mentioning this because after some research I did encounter threads about "ancillary data",for example: [Is there a way to get the uid of the other end of a unix socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898961/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-uid-of-the-other-end-of-a-unix-socket-connection)

Ancillary data contain credentials of the connecting socket(such as PID), but only work on **AF_UNIX** sockets, used for local IPC, and requires us to explicitly send/receive it on both sides(client/server). In my case, although, as I mentioned, the server will only proxy traffic on the same machine as the server, I need to use **AF_INET** sockets, so everyone(e.g. web browser) is able to connect to it.

Performance is not so critical; so any suggestions(including workarounds using system calls etc.) are very welcome.

Comment: A connection through a socket can be from any machine. It would amaze me if you could get the PID of the connecting process.

Comment: ***Why*** do you need the PID of the remove process? What is the real and original problem you attempt to solve with that?

Comment: This proxy is actually going to be a gateway in a bigger framework of filters and PID is required to be logged for other purposes than proxying.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, I agree with you, I do not need PIDs of processes on remote machines, actually as I mentioned in my question, this proxy is only destined to perform it's task for processes running on the same machine as itself. and I need those pids

Comment: As per my previous comment, sockets do not provide a means to get the PID of the connecting process. Hence you can't. Not even for a local process.

Comment: Yes @PaulOgilvie, thank you very much, but I am very well aware of that; still, there sure are ways to go about it, other than relying on the data provided by sockets; and I would appreciate if someone with linux/networking/c experience would point me in the direction of some clever workaround

Comment: For a connected TCP socket, you can obtain the address and port of the peer, and if on the same machine, use `lsof -F p -iTCP@address:port` to obtain the list of processes connected or bound to that address.  If there are only two, then one of them is your own process, and the other the connecting process.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, please read the entire question(including the use case), before commenting, as I said, a client can be anyone(including web browser), I do not write all the clients

Comment: @NominalAnimal, thanks for your suggestion, I will look into it!

Comment: Having a privileged helper program run and parse the output of `netstat -nptW` would be my suggestion; the proxy would then run it via `popen()` whenever it accepted a new connection to forward. This should be much more efficient than `lsof`. Should I expand that (the C source for such a helper) as an answer?

Comment: @NominalAnimal I would be very grateful if you did that, yes. And fyi, sudo privileges are no problem. Thank you.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Feel free to be amazed by my example code. Joking aside, the mechanism in my example finds the information via the Linux kernel networking subsystem using `netstat`, not using sockets per se. A similar semi-cross-platform approach is possible via `lsof`, or by adjusting to the output of `netstat` on other OSes. Sockets themselves are not the only way such information can be obtained, so your upvoted comment above is demonstrably incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `netstat -nptW` output to see which local processes' TCP connections. As the output may be security sensitive, superuser privileges are required to see processes belonging to all users.

Since there is no reason to run a proxy service with elevated privileges (expect perhaps `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE`), a privileged helper program is needed.

I pondered a suitable security model for a bit, and came to the conclusion that a helper which examines the connected socket given to it (as say standard input), and outputs just the peer PID(s), would be safest: it would be extremely hard to misuse it, and even if possible, only the peer process ID is revealed.

Here is the example helper, **tcp-peer-pids.c**:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define   EXITCODE_OK               0
#define   EXITCODE_STDIN_INVALID    1
#define   EXITCODE_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS  2
#define   EXITCODE_NETSTAT          3
#define   EXITCODE_NETSTAT_OUTPUT   4
#define   EXITCODE_WRITE_ERROR      5
#define   EXITCODE_PRIVILEGES       6

static pid_t        *pids = NULL;
static size_t    num_pids = 0;
static size_t    max_pids = 0;

static int add_pid(const pid_t p)
{
    size_t  i;

    /* Check if already listed. */
    for (i = 0; i < num_pids; i++)
        if (pids[i] == p)
            return 0;

    /* Ensure enough room in pids array. */
    if (num_pids >= max_pids) {
        const size_t  max_temp = (num_pids | 1023) + 1025 - 8;
        pid_t            *temp;

        temp = realloc(pids, max_temp * sizeof pids[0]);
        if (!temp)
            return ENOMEM;

        pids     = temp;
        max_pids = max_temp;
    }

    pids[num_pids++] = p;

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_storage  sock_addr;
    socklen_t                sock_addrlen = sizeof sock_addr;
    char                     sock_match[128], sock_host[64], sock_port[32];

    struct sockaddr_storage  peer_addr;
    socklen_t                peer_addrlen = sizeof peer_addr;
    char                     peer_match[128], peer_host[64], peer_port[32];

    FILE                    *cmd;
    char                    *line = NULL;
    size_t                   size = 0;
    ssize_t                  len;

    int                      status;

    /* Socket address is *remote*, and peer address is *local*.
       This is because the variables are named after their matching netstat lines. */
    if (getsockname(STDIN_FILENO, (struct sockaddr *)&sock_addr, &sock_addrlen) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Standard input is not a valid socket.\n");
        exit(EXITCODE_STDIN_INVALID);
    }
    if (getpeername(STDIN_FILENO, (struct sockaddr *)&peer_addr, &peer_addrlen) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Standard input is not a connected socket.\n");
        exit(EXITCODE_STDIN_INVALID);
    }
    if ((sock_addr.ss_family != AF_INET && sock_addr.ss_family != AF_INET6) ||
        (peer_addr.ss_family != AF_INET && peer_addr.ss_family != AF_INET6)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Standard input is not an IP socket.\n");
        exit(EXITCODE_STDIN_INVALID);
    }

    /* For security, we close the standard input descriptor, */
    close(STDIN_FILENO);

    /* and redirect it from /dev/null, if possible. */
    {
        int  fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY);
        if (fd != -1 && fd != STDIN_FILENO) {
            dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd);
        }
    }

    /* Convert sockets to numerical host and port strings. */
    if (getnameinfo((const struct sockaddr *)&sock_addr, sock_addrlen,
                    sock_host, sizeof sock_host, sock_port, sizeof sock_port,
                    NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unknown socket address.\n");
        exit(EXITCODE_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS);
    }
    if (getnameinfo((const struct sockaddr *)&peer_addr, peer_addrlen,
                    peer_host, sizeof peer_host, peer_port, sizeof peer_port,
                    NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unknown peer address.\n");
        exit(EXITCODE_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS);
    }

    /* Combine to the host:port format netstat uses. */
    snprintf(sock_match, sizeof sock_match, "%s:%s", sock_host, sock_port);
    snprintf(peer_match, sizeof peer_match, "%s:%s", peer_host, peer_port);

    /* Switch to privileged user, if installed as setuid. */
    {
        uid_t  real_uid = getuid();
        gid_t  real_gid = getgid();
        uid_t  effective_uid = geteuid();
        gid_t  effective_gid = getegid();
        if (real_gid != effective_gid || real_uid != effective_uid) {
            /* SetUID or SetGID in effect. Switch privileges. */
            if (setresgid(effective_gid, effective_gid, effective_gid) == -1 ||
                setresuid(effective_uid, effective_uid, effective_uid) == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error in privileges: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(EXITCODE_PRIVILEGES);
            }
        }
    }

    /* Run netstat to obtain the data; redirect standard error to standard output. */
    cmd = popen("LANG=C LC_ALL=C /bin/netstat -nptW 2>&1", "r");
    if (!cmd) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot run netstat.\n");
        exit(EXITCODE_NETSTAT);
    }

    /* Input line loop. */
    while (1) {
        char *field[8], *ends;
        long  val;
        pid_t p;

        len = getline(&line, &size, cmd);
        if (len < 1)
            break;

        /* Split each line into fields. */
        field[0] = strtok(line, "\t\n\v\f\r ");  /* Protocol */

        /* We are only interested in tcp ("tcp" and "tcp6" protocols). */
        if (strcmp(field[0], "tcp") && strcmp(field[0], "tcp6"))
            continue;

        field[1] = strtok(NULL, "\t\n\v\f\r ");  /* Recv-Q */
        field[2] = strtok(NULL, "\t\n\v\f\r ");  /* Send-Q */
        field[3] = strtok(NULL, "\t\n\v\f\r ");  /* Local address (peer) */
        field[4] = strtok(NULL, "\t\n\v\f\r ");  /* Remote address (sock) */
        field[5] = strtok(NULL, "\t\n\v\f\r ");  /* State */
        field[6] = strtok(NULL, "\t\n\v\f\r /"); /* PID */
        field[7] = strtok(NULL, "\t\n\v\f\r ");  /* Process name */

        /* Local address must match peer_match, and foreign/remote sock_match. */
        if (strcmp(field[3], peer_match) || strcmp(field[4], sock_match))
            continue;

        /* This line corresponds to the process we are looking for. */

        /* Missing PID field is an error at this point. */
        if (!field[6])
            break;

        /* Parse the PID. Parsing errors are fatal. */
        ends = field[6];
        errno = 0;
        val = strtol(field[6], &ends, 10);
        if (errno || ends == field[6] || *ends != '\0' || val < 1)
            break;
        p = (pid_t)val;
        if ((long)p != val)
            break;

        /* Add the pid to the known pids list. */
        if (add_pid(p))
            break;
    }

    /* The line buffer is no longer needed. */
    free(line);

    /* I/O error? */
    if (!feof(cmd) || ferror(cmd)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading netstat output.\n");
        exit(EXITCODE_NETSTAT_OUTPUT);
    }

    /* Reap the netstat process. */
    status = pclose(cmd);
    if (status == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading netstat output: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXITCODE_NETSTAT_OUTPUT);
    }               
    if (!WIFEXITED(status)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Netstat died unexpectedly.\n");
        exit(EXITCODE_NETSTAT_OUTPUT);
    }
    if (WEXITSTATUS(status)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Netstat failed with exit status %d.\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
        exit(EXITCODE_NETSTAT_OUTPUT);
    }        

    /* Output the array of pids as binary data. */
    if (num_pids > 0) {
        const char        *head = (const char *)pids;
        const char *const  ends = (const char *)(pids + num_pids);
        ssize_t            n;

        while (head < ends) {
            n = write(STDOUT_FILENO, head, (size_t)(ends - head));
            if (n > 0)
                head += n;
            else
            if (n != -1)
                exit(EXITCODE_WRITE_ERROR);
            else
            if (errno != EINTR)
                exit(EXITCODE_WRITE_ERROR);
        }
    }

    /* Discard the pids array. */
    free(pids);
    exit(EXITCODE_OK);
}
```

It can be run using ordinary user privileges (in which case it'll only know about processes owned by that user), root privileges, or as setuid root.

If used with `sudo`, ensure you use rule `proxyuser ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/helper`, because `sudo` has no way of asking a password there. I would probably just install the helper as setuid root at `/usr/lib/yourproxy/tcp-peer-pid`, owner root, group your proxy service group, and no access to other users (root:proxygroup `-r-sr-x---`).

The helper is tightly coupled to `netstat -nptW` output format, but does explicitly set the C locale to avoid getting localized output.

The comparison `address:port` strings to match to "Local Address" and "Foreign Address" in netstat output are constructed from the addresses returned by [`getpeername()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html) and [`getsockname()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html), respectively, using [`getnameinfo()`(http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getnameinfo.3.html) in numerical form (using `NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV` flags).

---

The helper provides the PIDs in binary form to the server, because the server code would have been too long to fit in a single post here otherwise.

Here is an example TCP service, **server.c**, which uses the above helper to find out the PID of the peer end of the socket on the local computer. (To avoid denial-of-service attacks, you should set an IP filter that rejects accesses to your proxy service port from outside the computer.)

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifndef  HELPER_PATH
#define  HELPER_PATH  "./tcp-peer-pids"
#endif
#ifndef  HELPER_NAME
#define  HELPER_NAME  "tcp-peer-pids"
#endif

#ifndef  SUDO_PATH
#define  SUDO_PATH    "/usr/bin/sudo"
#endif
#ifndef  SUDO_NAME
#define  SUDO_NAME    "sudo"
#endif

/*
 * Signal handler, to detect INT (Ctrl+C), HUP, and TERM signals.
*/

static volatile sig_atomic_t  done = 0;

static void handle_done(int signum)
{
    /* In Linux, all signals have signum > 0. */
    __atomic_store_n(&done, (sig_atomic_t)signum, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
}

static int install_done(int signum)
{
    struct sigaction  act;

    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;  /* Do not interrupt slow syscalls. */
    act.sa_handler = handle_done;
    if (sigaction(signum, &act, NULL) == -1)
        return -1; /* errno set by getpeername() */

    return 0;
}

/* Helper function: Move descriptors away from STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR.
   Returns 0 if successful, -1 with errno set if an error occurs. */
static inline int normalfds(int fd[], const size_t n)
{
    unsigned int  closemask = 0;
    int           err = 0;
    size_t        i;    
    int           newfd;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        while (fd[i] == STDIN_FILENO || fd[i] == STDOUT_FILENO || fd[i] == STDERR_FILENO) {
            newfd = dup(fd[i]);
            if (newfd == -1) {
                err = errno;
                break;
            }
            closemask |= 1u << fd[i];
            fd[i] = newfd;
        }

    /* Close temporary descriptors. */
    if (closemask & (1u <<  STDIN_FILENO)) close(STDIN_FILENO);
    if (closemask & (1u << STDOUT_FILENO)) close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    if (closemask & (1u << STDERR_FILENO)) close(STDERR_FILENO);

    /* Success? */
    if (!err)
        return 0;

    /* Report error. */
    errno = err;
    return -1;
}

/* Return the number of peer processes.
   If an error occurs, returns zero; examine errno. */
size_t  peer_pids(const int connfd, pid_t *const pids, size_t maxpids)
{
    char   *in_data = NULL;
    size_t  in_size = 0;
    size_t  in_used = 0;
    size_t  n;
    int     binpipe[2], status;
    pid_t   child, p;

    /* Sanity check. */
    if (connfd == -1) {
        errno = EBADF;
        return 0;
    }

    /* Create a pipe to transfer the PIDs (in binary). */
    if (pipe(binpipe) == -1)
        return 0; /* errno set by pipe(). */

    /* Make sure the binary pipe descriptors do not conflict with standard descriptors. */
    if (normalfds(binpipe, 2) == -1) {
        const int  saved_errno = errno;
        close(binpipe[0]);
        close(binpipe[1]);
        errno = saved_errno;
        return 0;
    }

    /* Fork a child process. */
    child = fork();
    if (child == -1) {
        const int  saved_errno = errno;
        close(binpipe[0]);
        close(binpipe[1]);
        errno = saved_errno;
        return 0;
    }

    if (!child) {
        /* This is the child process. */

#ifdef USE_SUDO
        const char  *cmd_path = SUDO_PATH;
        char *const  cmd_args[3] = { SUDO_NAME, HELPER_PATH, NULL };
#else
        const char  *cmd_path = HELPER_PATH;
        char *const  cmd_args[2] = { HELPER_NAME, NULL };
#endif

        /* The child runs in its own process group, for easier management. */
        setsid();

        /* Close read end of pipe. */
        close(binpipe[0]);

        /* Move established connection to standard input. */
        if (connfd != STDIN_FILENO) {
            if (dup2(connfd, STDIN_FILENO) != STDIN_FILENO)
                _Exit(99);
            close(connfd);
        }

        /* Move write end of pipe to standard output. */
        if (dup2(binpipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO) != STDOUT_FILENO)
            _Exit(99);
        else
            close(binpipe[1]);

        /* Execute helper. */
        execv(cmd_path, cmd_args);

        /* Failed to execute helper. */
        _Exit(98);
    }

    /* Parent process. */

    /* Close write end of pipe, so we detect when child exits. */
    close(binpipe[1]);

    /* Read all output from child. */
    status = 0;
    while (1) {
        ssize_t  bytes;

        if (in_used >= in_size) {
            const size_t  size = (in_used | 1023) + 1025 - 8;
            char         *temp;

            temp = realloc(in_data, in_size);
            if (!temp) {
                status = ENOMEM;
                break;
            }
            in_data = temp;
            in_size = size;
        }

        bytes = read(binpipe[0], in_data + in_used, in_size - in_used);
        if (bytes > 0) {
            in_used += bytes;
        } else
        if (bytes == 0) {
            /* End of input condition. */
            break;
        } else
        if (bytes != -1) {
            status = EIO;
            break;
        } else
        if (errno != EINTR) {
            status = errno;
            break;
        }
    }

    /* Close the pipe. */
    close(binpipe[0]);

    /* Abort, if an error occurred. */
    if (status) {
        free(in_data);
        kill(-child, SIGKILL);
        do {
            p = waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
        } while (p == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        errno = status;
        return 0;
    }

    /* Reap the child process. */
    do {
        status = 0;
        p = waitpid(child, &status, 0);
    } while (p == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (p == -1) {
        const int  saved_errno = errno;
        free(in_data);
        errno = saved_errno;
        return 0;
    }
    if (!WIFEXITED(status) || WEXITSTATUS(status) != 0) {
        free(in_data);
        errno = ESRCH; /* The helper command failed, really. */
        return 0;
    }

    /* We expect an integer number of pid_t's. Check. */
    n = in_used / sizeof (pid_t);
    if ((in_used % sizeof (pid_t)) != 0) {
        free(in_data);
        errno = EIO;
        return 0;
    }

    /* None found? */
    if (!n) {
        free(in_data);
        errno = ENOENT; /* Not found, really. */
        return 0;
    }

    /* Be paranoid, and verify the pids look sane. */
    {
        const pid_t *const pid = (const pid_t *const)in_data;
        size_t             i;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (pid[i] < 2) {
                free(in_data);
                errno = ESRCH; /* Helper failed */
                return 0;
            }
    }

    /* Copy to user buffer, if specified. */
    if (maxpids > n)
        memcpy(pids, in_data, n * sizeof (pid_t));
    else
    if (maxpids > 0)
        memcpy(pids, in_data, maxpids * sizeof (pid_t));

    /* The pid buffer is no longer needed. */
    free(in_data);

    /* Return the number of pids we actually received. */
    return n;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo          hints, *list, *curr;
    const char              *node, *serv;
    int                      service_fd, err;

    struct sockaddr_storage  client_addr;
    socklen_t                client_addrlen;
    int                      client_fd;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s HOST PORT\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Install signal handers for Ctrl+C, HUP, and TERM. */
    if (install_done(SIGINT) ||
        install_done(SIGHUP) ||
        install_done(SIGTERM)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot install signal handlers: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Empty or - or * is a wildcard host. */
    if (argv[1][0] == '\0' || !strcmp(argv[1], "-") || !strcmp(argv[1], "*"))
        node = NULL;
    else
        node = argv[1];
    serv = argv[2];

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; /* IPv4 or IPv6 */
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; /* TCP */
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;
    hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
    hints.ai_addr = NULL;
    hints.ai_next = NULL;
    list = NULL;
    err = getaddrinfo(node, serv, &hints, &list);
    if (err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid host and/or port: %s.\n", gai_strerror(err));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    service_fd = -1;
    err = 0;
    for (curr = list; curr != NULL; curr = curr->ai_next) {
        service_fd = socket(curr->ai_family, curr->ai_socktype, curr->ai_protocol);
        if (service_fd == -1)
            continue;

        errno = 0;
        if (bind(service_fd, curr->ai_addr, curr->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            if (!err)
                if (errno == EADDRINUSE || errno == EADDRNOTAVAIL || errno == EACCES)
                    err = errno;
            close(service_fd);
            service_fd = -1;
            continue;
        }

        if (listen(service_fd, 5) == -1) {
            if (!err)
                if (errno == EADDRINUSE)
                    err = errno;
            close(service_fd);
            service_fd = -1;
            continue;
        }

        /* This socket works. */
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(list);
    list = curr = NULL;

    if (service_fd == -1) {
        if (err)
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot listen for incoming connections on the specified host and port: %s.\n", strerror(err));
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot listen for incoming connections on the specified host and port.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Do not leak the listening socket to child processes. */
    fcntl(service_fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);

    /* We also want the listening socket to be nonblocking. */
    fcntl(service_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    fprintf(stderr, "Process %ld is waiting for incoming TCP connections.\n", (long)getpid());

    /* Incoming connection loop. */
    while (!done) {
        struct timeval t;
        char    client_host[64]; /* 64 for numeric, 1024 for non-numeric */
        char    client_port[32];
        pid_t   client_pid;
        fd_set  fds;

        t.tv_sec = 0;
        t.tv_usec = 100000; /* Max. 0.1s delay to react to done signal. */

        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(service_fd, &fds);

        if (select(service_fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &t) < 1)
            continue;

        client_addrlen = sizeof client_addr;
        client_fd = accept(service_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_addrlen);
        if (client_fd == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR || errno == ECONNABORTED)
                continue;
            fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting an incoming connection: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            continue;
        }

        if (getnameinfo((const struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, client_addrlen,
                        client_host, sizeof client_host, client_port, sizeof client_port,
                        NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot resolve peer address for incoming connection, so dropping it.\n");
            close(client_fd);
            continue;
        }

        printf("Incoming connection from %s:%s", client_host, client_port);
        fflush(stdout);

        if (peer_pids(client_fd, &client_pid, 1) != 1) {
            printf(", but cannot determine process ID. Dropped.\n");
            close(client_fd);
            continue;
        }

        printf(" from local process %ld.\n", (long)client_pid);
        fflush(stdout);

        /*
         * Handle connection.
        */

        printf("Closing connection.\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        close(client_fd);
    }

    /* Close service socket. */
    close(service_fd);

    switch (__atomic_load_n(&done, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST)) {
    case SIGINT:
        fprintf(stderr, "Received INT signal.\n");
        break;
    case SIGHUP:
        fprintf(stderr, "Received HUP signal.\n");
        break;
    case SIGTERM:
        fprintf(stderr, "Received TERM signal.\n");
        break;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `peer_pids()` function communicates with the helper process. It is very straightforward, albeit careful to not return unreliable data: instead of ignoring errors or trying to recover from them, it reports failure.  This allows the main program do `if (peer_pids(client_fd, &pid, 1) != 1) /* Don't know! */` and drop any connection the server is unsure of -- an approach I consider the sane one here.

The `normalfds()` helper function is often ignored. It helps avoid issues if any of the standard streams are/get closed. It simply moves the set of descriptors away from the three standard streams, using at most three extra descriptors.

You can define `USE_SUDO` at compile time to have it use sudo when executing the helper. Define `HELPER_PATH` and `HELPER_NAME` to the absolute path to the helper and its file name, respectively. (As it is now, they default to `./tcp-peer-pid` and `tcp-peer-pid`, for easier testing.)

The server does install a signal handler for INT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), HUP (sent when the user closes the terminal), or TERM signals, which all cause it to stop accepting new connections and exit in a controlled manner. (Because the signal handler is installed using `SA_RESTART` flag, its delivery will not interrupt slow syscalls or cause `errno == EINTR`. This also means that `accept()` should not block, or the signal delivery will not be noticed. So, blocking in `select()` for 0.1s, and checking if a signal was delivered in between, is a good compromise, at least in an example server.)

---

On my machine, I compiled and tested the service in one terminal window using

```
gcc -Wall -O2 tcp-peer-pids.c -o tcp-peer-pids
gcc -Wall -O2 "-DHELPER_PATH=\"$PWD/tcp-peer-pids\"" server.c -o server
./server - 2400
```

That will report `Process # is waiting for incoming TCP connections`. In another window, using Bash or POSIX shell, I run one or more test netcat commands:

```
nc localhost 2400 & wait
```

It might look silly to run a command in the background, and immediately wait for it, but that way you can see the PID of the `nc` process.

On my system, all loopback (`127.x.y.z`), TCP/IPv4, and TCP/IPv6 (the addresses of my ethernet and WiFi interfaces) worked fine, and reliably reported the correct PID of the process connecting to the example server.

There are a number of cases where the number of PIDs reported might vary: For example, if the program has executed a child process, but left the connected descriptor open in the child as well. (This should be considered a bug.) Another typical case is the program having exited before the `netstat` command executes.

If you find any typos or errors or strange behaviour, let me know in a comment so I can verify and fix.  I wrote both programs in one sitting, so they are quite likely to contain bugs.  As I mentioned, I would not trust either in production before having a colleague (or myself a few times, later on, with fresh eyes) going through it with a critical/paranoid eye.

---

I would personally only use this approach for logging and statistics, not access control per se.  By access control, I mean that you should configure an IP filter (the firewall built in to the Linux kernel) to limit access to only trusted hosts; and specifically allow no incoming proxy connections to the proxy service if only local applications are to be proxied, rather than rely on this detecting all remote connections.

For application-specific logging/limiting, use [`readlink()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) on the `/proc/PID/exe` pseudosymlink. This cannot be faked, but the call may fail if the executable is not accessible, or is too deep in the directory tree. (In those cases I'd reject the proxy connection altogether.)

Note that it is usually trivial for an user to copy an executable to any directory they own, and execute it from there.  This means that for application-specific limiting to work at all, you should have tight limits for all applications by default, and *relax* the limits for specific executables.

Comment: Rather than relying on `netstat`, it would be possible to use a privileged "companion" process that uses netlink to obtain the same information as `netstat`, but keeping track of the proxy sockets only.  In fact, I believe that might be even better approach than the one shown here, due to less overhead; for porting to other systems, the companion could be adapted for each OS separately.